# Records in log file

Tags: joomla-2.5, php, joomla-api

In my site logs folder when i open error.php, i see lots of records per line as one is look like this -

```
2014-04-03  22:35:54    INFO    2.61.174.50 Joomla FAILURE:     Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet.
```

What does that mean actually as i never had to deal with logs in joomla. As far as i get, most probably someone tried to access my admin login and joomla logged it, is a hacking attempt? if it is, then the above IP banning is sufficient?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't necessarily mean someone has tried to login into the backend. Simply means someone has tried to

- Login to the frontend **or** backend
- On the 3rd April 2014
- At 10:35pm
- From this IP address: *2.61.174.50*

If you login to your server control panel (if you have one), you can check the raw logs. If you filter by the IP address given, and find a result, it will show you the URL they tried to access.